PHP login error when username and password are correct
PHP login error when username and password are correct
`Hello so I am doing this tutorial from php academy for a php and mysql login and registration form. It was going okay.. he was showing how to idk what the correct way to say it but to create functions to echo errors.. yeah that sounds right. So the first couple errors echoed correctly but the one to actually validate the tb_pengguna and whatknot, isn't working. Its showing the error I created when the username and password combination is incorrect even when i submit the correct information. I've created a few dummy users and none of them can get through.
this is my code...`
<?php 
include "inc/koneksi.php";

        if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {  
        
        

            $username=mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi,$_POST['username']);
            $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($koneksi,md5($_POST['password']));


        $sql_login = "SELECT * FROM tb_pengguna WHERE BINARY username='$username' AND password= '$password'";
        $query_login = mysqli_query($koneksi, $sql_login);
        $data_login = mysqli_fetch_array($query_login,MYSQLI_BOTH);
        $jumlah_login = mysqli_num_rows($query_login);
        

            if ($jumlah_login == 1 ){
              session_start();
              $_SESSION["ses_id"]=$data_login["id_pengguna"];
              $_SESSION["ses_nama"]=$data_login["nama_pengguna"];
              $_SESSION["ses_username"]=$data_login["username"];
              $_SESSION["ses_password"]=$data_login["password"];
              $_SESSION["ses_level"]=$data_login["level"];
                
              echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({title: 'Login Berhasil',
                        text: '',
                        icon: 'success',
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            window.location = 'index.php';
                        }
                    })</script>";
              }else{
              echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({title: 'Login Gagal',
                        text: '',
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText: 'OK'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            window.location = 'login.php';
                        }
                    })</script>";
                }
              }


`does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I've tried a few things and nothing works. For example in the video he does it a little different and puts his queries in line but that was giving me errors so i did it the way he originally had it and made the queries variables  but that fixed the errors. I tried doing that to the other functions (not shown) but that caused a whole lot of errors :(
`

Not sure what tutorial you're following but unfortunately this code is insecure and obsolete in multiple ways. Don't use it, and don't follow this guide again. To make a secure login system, at minimum you need to hash passwords using password_hash and verify them using password_verify. md5 has been insecure for many years now. And you must prepare your SQL queries properly and use parameters and placeholders for the inputs- see sites like https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for more details and good examples. mysqli_real_escape_string is obsolete and can't protect against everything
